# how to bind image in Listbox with data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, c#-3.0

Hi all i have one problem in list box in which i would like to bind image with data on condition . Like when user is active i like to display different image , when he is not working like to display different image . this time i am displaying name in different color on his status like not working then in Red color, working with green color.

My html is

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ddlDriver" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDriver_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                runat="server"  BackColor="White" Height="380px">



                                        </asp:ListBox>
```

Code :

```
   if (_driv.DriverStatus == 1)
        {
            ddlDriver.Items[i].Text = ddlDriver.Items[i].Value + "-" + ddlDriver.Items[i].Text + " " + OrderTota;
            ddlDriver.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "red");

        }
        else if (_driv.DriverStatus == 2)
        {
            ddlDriver.Items[i].Text = ddlDriver.Items[i].Value + "-" + ddlDriver.Items[i].Text + " " + OrderTota;
            ddlDriver.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "green");
        }
```

please help me about this issue.

Comment: This is not an asp-classic issue. remove that tag

Answer (score 0):

You may define two css classes with appropriate background-image property and conditionally set class on items in code-behind